# How do dermatologists make a differential Diagnosis between Psoriasis, Parapsoriasis and Skin Lymphoma in an otherwise healthy person?

Tags: dermatology, cancer, differential-diagnosis, psoriasis

It seems to me, from the following Google Images search, that the **dermatological** symptoms for [Psoriasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psoriasis), [Parapsoriasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parapsoriasis) and [Skin Lymphoma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphoma) are quite similar, excluding a certain type of Psoriasis named *Reverse Psoriasis* or *Inverse Psoriasis*<sup>[1](https://www.google.it/search?q=reverse%20psoriasis&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjtguz0g_j_AhURpicCHSA2Bm0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=reverse%20psoriasis&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQExCABDoECAAQHlCiAljXA2DVBWgAcAB4AIABeYgB5AKSAQMwLjOYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=IKClZO3yKpHMnsEPoOyY6AY&bih=929&biw=1920)</sup> which is more similar to eczema (given that no skin peels) than to the other three situations I have described above.

- [Psoriasis images](https://www.google.it/search?q=Psoriasis%20symptoms&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiPvoDWg_j_AhVtpicCHT68BE8Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Psoriasis%20symptoms&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABFAAWMwOYLEPaAFwAHgBgAGoAYgB3QmSAQMxLjmYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=4J-lZI_OAe3MnsEPvviS-AQ&bih=929&biw=1920)
- [Parapsoriasis images](https://www.google.it/search?q=parapsoriasis%20symptoms&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiTms_Xg_j_AhUUpkwKHa_IAP8Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=parapsoriasis%20symptoms&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQExCABFCgBVjuDGDjEGgAcAB4AIABpAGIAaQGkgEDMC42mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=45-lZNOcGZTMsgKvkYP4Dw&bih=929&biw=1920)
- [Skin Lymphoma images](https://www.google.it/search?q=Skin%20Lymphoma%20symptoms&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj2grPeg_j_AhXspicCHZXJDp4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Skin%20Lymphoma%20symptoms&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQExCABDIHCAAQExCABDIICAAQBRAeEBMyCAgAEAUQHhATMggIABAFEB4QEzIICAAQBRAeEBMyCAgAEAUQHhATMggIABAFEB4QEzIICAAQBRAeEBMyCAgAEAUQHhATOgcIABCKBRBDOgUIABCABDoECAAQHjoGCAAQCBAeUMcEWNwoYMEpaAJwAHgAgAGQAYgBjxiSAQQwLjI0mAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=8Z-lZLbGJuzNnsEPlZO78Ak&bih=929&biw=1920)
- [Reverse Psoriasis images](https://www.google.it/search?q=reverse%20psoriasis&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjtguz0g_j_AhURpicCHSA2Bm0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=reverse%20psoriasis&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCAAQExCABDoECAAQHlCiAljXA2DVBWgAcAB4AIABeYgB5AKSAQMwLjOYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=IKClZO3yKpHMnsEPoOyY6AY&bih=929&biw=1920) (dissimilar to the three above and in my opinion more similar to [Eczema](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eczema))

How do dermatologists make a differential Diagnosis between Psoriasis, Parapsoriasis and Skin Lymphoma in an otherwise healthy person?